# Issue creating a reference array - VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

The goal of my code is to create an array of values in an excel column and for each value, check to see if it is found in a text file or not. A message box will show which values were found and which ones need to be added to the text file. The array idxArr holds the values to check against the text file (read in via Line Input). I want to parse the text file and add any elements found to the foundIdx array.  Currently, my code is reading in each line of the text file and if any of the members of idxarr are not found, it will go back to the Do while statement, which resets my foundIdx array to 0. I've tried changing the scope of countf = 0 but can't seem to get the code to work. Any ideas about how to correctly create this reference array? The functions below the main sub create an array of values in my spreadsheet and check to see if a value is already in an array in order to populate another array of values that were not found in the text file.

Code below:

```
Dim txtfilename As String, devpath As String, TextLine As String
Dim idxsource As Workbook
Dim lenRange As Range, idxRange As Range
Dim lenCount As Integer, Count As Integer
Dim idxArr As Collection
Dim blnFound As Boolean
Dim foundIdx() As Variant
Dim missngIdx() As Variant
Dim countf As Long
Dim countm As Long

txtfilename = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("Txtfile_name")

Set idxsource = Workbooks.Open("filepath" & txtfilename & "\" & txtfilename & "_qualifier.xlsx")


Set lenRange = idxsource.Sheets(1).Columns(1)
lenCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(lenRange)

Set idxRange = idxsource.Sheets(1).Range("T2:T" & lenCount)


Set idxArr = GetIndices(idxRange.Value)


devpath = text file path

Open devpath For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
 Line Input #1, TextLine
    Text = Text + TextLine
    countf = 0
    For Each UIndex In idxArr
        If UIndex = "" Then GoTo NextUIndex
            If InStr(1, TextLine, UIndex, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
                blnFound = True
                ' Assign any Indices found into an array
                    If blnFound = True Then
                        ReDim foundIdx(countf)
                        foundIdx(countf) = UIndex
                        countf = countf + 1
                    End If
            End If
NextUIndex:
   Next UIndex
Loop

Close #1


    countm = 0
    For Each LIndex In idxArr
        If LIndex = "" Then GoTo NLIndex
        If IsInArray(LIndex, foundIdx) = True Then 'GoTo NLIndex Else
            ReDim Preserve missngIdx(countm)
            missngIdx(countm) = ""
            countm = countm + 1
            Else:
            ReDim Preserve missngIdx(countm)
            missngIdx(countm) = LIndex
            countm = countm + 1
        End If
NLIndex:
    Next LIndex

' Print found Indices
For i = LBound(foundIdx) To UBound(foundIdx)
        msg = msg & foundIdx(i) & vbNewLine
Next i
MsgBox "Validated the following indices: " & vbNewLine & msg

' Print missing Indices
If missngIdx(0) = "" Then
'If IsEmpty(missngIdx) = True Then
    MsgBox "All indices have been found!"
Else
   For i = LBound(missngIdx) To UBound(missngIdx)
      msg1 = msg1 & missngIdx(i) & vbNewLine
    Next i
    MsgBox "The following indices need to be added to the text file: " & vbNewLine & msg1
End If

End Sub

Public Function GetIndices(ByVal IndexRange As Variant) As Collection

' Objective is to input the Range where indices are located and create an array of unique values to use for looking through the ci
' to validate that all indices have been entered into the cdi

Dim Indices As Collection
Dim cellValue As Variant
Dim cellValuetrimmed As String

Set Indices = New Collection
Set GetIndices = Indices

On Error Resume Next

' 1. Trim values in range and skip empty cells.
' 2. Add values into the Indices Collection. "Contains" function will check the collection
' to look for duplicates

For Each cellValue In IndexRange
    cellValuetrimmed = Trim(cellValue)
    If cellValuetrimmed = "" Then GoTo NextValue
    If Contains(Indices, cellValuetrimmed) = True Then GoTo NextValue
    Indices.Add cellValuetrimmed
NextValue:
    Next cellValue

On Error GoTo 0

End Function

Public Function Contains(Col As Collection, key As Variant) As Boolean
Dim obj As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim ret As Boolean
On Err GoTo Err
    For i = 1 To Col.Count
        If Col(i) = key Then
            ret = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    Contains = ret
    Exit Function
Err:
    Contains = False
End Function

Public Function IsInArray(val As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
Dim element As Variant
On Error GoTo ArrErr:
    For Each element In arr
        If element = val Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next element
Exit Function:
ArrErr:
On Error GoTo 0
IsInArray = False
End Function
```

Comment: `ReDim Preserve`. You're blowing away the contents of your array each time you add an element.

Comment: Save yourself a lot of pain and read up on scripting.dictionaries. use idxArr to setup the keys of a dictionary then each word you read in is just idxArr.exists(word).